# Linear Gradient hr effect only works in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have this div that looks like a hr line.
The styles only work in Firefox.

I created a Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vLFN7/

```
<mydiv> </mydiv>
mydiv {

  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    border: 0 none;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0 40px;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/vLFN7/4/)

Problem is fixed when you use `to left`

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent,
                                  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
```

Read the [linear-gradient - CSS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

Comment: That worked for Firefox and Opera but my Chrome still does not display it. Any suggestions?

Comment: For some reason my Chrome does not display it, only white. Maybe because it is Portable version. Anyway I did this for it and it worked : background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0));

Comment: strange, if I use "to left" it does not work but with just "left" it does.

Answer (score 0):

It is works in all.

```
div {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left center , transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), transparent);
    border: 0 none;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0 40px;
}
```